# Changing default port of keycloak in docker

Tags: keycloak

I have logged in to virtual machine in docker but I can't find standalone.sh It isn't in /bin. I don't know also how to write dockerfile which set -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass port as -Djboss.http.port parameter, for example:

```
 docker run --name keycloak -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -p 11111:11111 jboss/keycloak -Djboss.http.port=11111
```

Comment: i tried this but got the following exceptions: 1. 01:17:11,185 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0113: '' is an invalid value for parameter user-name. Values must have a minimum length of 1 characters" and a few more.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your error message doesn't look like related to the port. Do you receive it only when you try to set different ports or in any case? It looks more like KEYCLOAK_USER variable is not set properly.

Comment: thanks - I was able to change the port by passing the port number after the command listed above

Comment: @YuriyP I am getting below error while executing above command               "7:03:44,000 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final
WFLYSRV0073: Invalid option '.http.port=11111'"

Comment: @meenu, I am not sure why such an error occurs. I just checked one more time and was able to run the command without any errors.

Answer (score 5):

Below is a sample docker-compose YAML file which shows you may set the offset in the command. Please kindly change according to your setting.

`version: '2.1'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:4.5.0.Final
    container_name: keycloak
    user: change_it
    hostname: change_it
    command: ["-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=0"]
    extra_hosts:
            - "change_it"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=change_it
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=change_it
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443`

Answer (score 5):

Using Keycloak 19+:

```yaml
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    command: ["start-dev", "--http-port=8888"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me as in to change the default port of keycloak server through docker file. (keycloak runs on localhost:8100)

```
keycloak:
    build:
      context: ./keycloak
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME: custom 
      KEYCLOAK_WELCOME_THEME: keycloak 
      DB_VENDOR: h2
    container_name: keycloak-container
    command: ["-Djboss.http.port=8100"]
    # Uncomment for development purpose
    # volumes:
    #   - ${PWD}/keycloak/theme/custom:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/custom
    ports:
      - 8100:8100
```